# Integer absolute value in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, absolute-value

Do you have any simple ways to make a value in a register in MIPS as an absolute value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple way to do it.

```
#assume you want the absolute value of r1
        ori $2, $zero, $1      #copy r1 into r2
        slt $3, $1, $zero      #is value < 0 ?
        beq $3, $zero, foobar  #if r1 is positive, skip next inst
        sub $2, $zero, $1      #r2 = 0 - r1
foobar:
#r2 now contains the absolute value of r1
```

Comment: Note that this is for a MIPS *without* branch-delay slots, like MARS / SPIM simulate by default.  Otherwise you'd want to rearrange the `move` (`ori`) into the branch-delay slot.

Answer (score 26):

Here's a branch-less variant:

```
# input and output in $t0
sra $t1,$t0,31   
xor $t0,$t0,$t1   
sub $t0,$t0,$t1
```

How does this work?
First, `$t1` is filled with the sign-bit of `$t0`. So if `$t0` is positive `$t1` will be set to 0, and if `$t0` is negative `$t1` will be set to 0xFFFFFFFF.
Next, each bit of `$t0` is inverted if `$t1` is 0xFFFFFFFF, or left unchanged if `$t1` is 0. It just so happens that inverting all bits of a number is the same as setting it to `(-number)-1` (in two's complement).
Finally, either 0xFFFFFFFF (which equals -1) or 0 is subtracted from the intermediate result.

So if `$t0` originally was negative you'll get:
`$t0 = ($t0 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF) - 0xFFFFFFFF` == `(-$t0 - 1) - -1` == `(-$t0 - 1) + 1` == `-$t0`.
And if it originally was positive you'll get:
`$t0 = ($t0 ^ 0) - 0` ==  `$t0`.

Comment: Warning: This method is covered by U.S. patent #6073150.  Probably invalid as hell, though, since it's been known longer than 1997.

Comment: @Myria: Compilers such as GCC have been using this for years on various ISAs.  e.g. GCC4.4 for x86-64: https://godbolt.org/z/Mv843o.  (Also shows 64-bit MIPS GCC5.4 using conditional move, `movn`, to select between `x` and `-x` like clang does for x86.)

Answer (score 10):

Simplest way of all.
There is a pseudo instruction that does this:

```
abs $t1, $t1
```

will take the absolute value of the value in register $t1 and place it in $t1

Comment: This pseudo-instruction is the `sra/xor/sub` sequence shown in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a size-optimized version of it.  It's slower than the sra/xor/subu answer, due to branch prediction issues, but it's one instruction smaller:

```
    bgtz $t0, label
label:
    subu $t0, $zero, $t0
```

This works because of the MIPS delay slot: if `$t0` is positive, the `subu` instruction to negate `$t0` executes twice.  You may need to enable `.set noreorder` in your assembler.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would just to do a bit of binary math on the values.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations describes how various systems store their negative numbers. I believe MIPS uses a *two's complement* scheme to store signed numbers. This makes it a bit harder than a bit flag, which could just be turned off by ANDing the number with 0b01111111, but it is still doable.