# Modifying a register based on whether a number is positive or negative

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips

I am new to assembly and MIPS, and wanted to practice my skills. I found some exercises online and decided to give them a shot. One which I am not quite sure about is the following:

> Set the value stored in $t0 to -1, if $t0 is negative, and 0 if $t0 is positive.

Would my approach be correct? Can this be done more efficiently using arithmetic shifting?

Here is my code:

```
main:
    li $t0, -5
    bgt $t0, $0, pos

    # must be negative
    li $t1, -1
    # negative so make t0 = -1
    srav $t0, $t0, $t1

    # end of program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall


pos:
    # positive so make t0 = 0
    sra $t0, $t0, 31

    # end of program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: `sra` by 31 broadcasts the sign bit, creating 0 or -1 (two's complement).  There's no need to branch around that.  (Assuming they actually mean negative vs. non-negative, or that a `0` result is allowed for a `0` input (which is neither negative nor positive).  You used `bgt` which falls through for 0.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks for pointing that out! I had a feeling like I overcomplicated this..

Comment: More importantly, right shift by `-1` is super weird.  IDK why you wouldn't just `li $t0, -1` if you were taking a branching strategy at all.  (Although that would expose the fact that `bgt` instead of `bge` is probably wrong).  I assume MIPS either saturates or masks shift counts that are out of range, so it probably has the same effect as `sra $t0, $t0, 31` in the negative branch as well, but less efficient and more obfuscated than the `pos` block.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [Integer absolute value in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16059870) contains `sra $t1,$t0,31` as part of a branchless bithack for integer absolute value.

Comment: That's great, thank you for posting this! I was not aware of the fact that we can actually avoid branching all-together and use such tricks. That will definitely come in handy.

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually have another quick question that is related. Does shifting by 31 have anything to do with the fact that MIPS is using a 32-bit architecture?

Comment: Yeah, MIPS even has `movn` and `movs` branchless conditional-move instructions, like some compilers use for absolute-value https://godbolt.org/z/eEzYKv3az

Comment: Yes, shifting by reg_width-1 is the entire point.  The original MSB goes to the bottom, and the higher bits are copies of it.  Shifts by more than 31 probably aren't possible (I'd have to check how MIPS handles that case), and shifts by less than 31 would leave some bits you don't want at the bottom of the register.  On MIPS64 you'd shift by 63.  I assumed you knew this because you already wrote `sra $t0, $t0, 31` in the `pos` path as a way to create a zero when the sign bit was known-0.  (Of course the normal way to create a zero is `li $t0, 0` or `move $t0, $zero`  :P)

Comment: @Peter Cordes I see! Thank you so much for all the detailed explanations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sra` by 31 broadcasts the sign bit, creating 0 (all bits clear) or -1 (all bits set, which is -1 on a two's complement system such as MIPS).

There's no need to branch around that, and you're already doing the same shift on both sides of the branch.  Arithmetic right shift by `reg_width - 1` (or more on ISAs where that's possible<sup>1</sup>) will turn the whole register into copies of the original sign bit.  The original MSB ends up at the LSB, and the rest of the bits are copies of that bit.

**Footnote 1:** It's not on MIPS.  MIPS shifts that take the count from a register only use the low 5 bits as the count [(MIPS32 instruction-set reference manual)](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/MIPS_Vol2.pdf), so `-1 & 31 = 31`.  And of course immediate-count shifts only have a 5-bit `shamt` field in the R-type instruction encoding.

---

So **non-negative** numbers (positive and zero) turn into `0`, negative numbers turn into `-1`.

It's super weird to `li` a `-1` as the count for an `srav` instead of just doing `sra $t0, $t0, 31`.  Or since you apparently just want to zero `$t0`, `li $t0, 0` or `move $t0, $zer0` if you're branching and know you want a 0 there.  Or without pseudo-instructions, `or $t0, $zero, $zero`)

---

**This trick is well-known** (among bit-hack aficionados and compiler developers), and used in many bit-hacks such as branchless `abs`: [Integer absolute value in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312543/integer-absolute-value-in-mips/16059870#16059870)

- [https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign)  is exactly this 0 / -1 decision.  (But in C where `>>` isn't guaranteed to be 2's complement arithmetic right shift, and `int` can have padding, hence calling it non-portable).
- https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks

(MIPS has other branchless conditional instructions like `slt` / `sltu`, and in later MIPS `movn` and `movs` branchless conditional-move instructions.  Some compilers use them for absolute-value: https://godbolt.org/z/eEzYKv3az)